# How to get json object from controller in zul ZK?

Tags: javascript, java, json, zk

I need to create a chart in zk using Google Chart, like below:

[image]

This is my controller:

```
public class ChartForm extends GenericComposer{

public List<Task> listTask;
public String json;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericComposer#doAfterCompose(org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component)
 */
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    TaskService ts = new TaskService();

    listTask = ts.getTask(); 

    json = new Gson().toJson(listTask); // I't OK until here

    System.out.println(json); 
}

}
```

The value is:

> [{"taskName":"Automation","hours":11},{"taskName":"Manual","hours":2},{"taskName":"Report","hours":2},{"taskName":"Payroll","hours":2},{"taskName":"MISC","hours":7}]

My zul:

```
<zk>
 <window id="HomePage" apply = "com.dom.form.ChartForm" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:green">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/chart/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Automation',     11],
          ['Manual',      2],
          ['Report',  2],
          ['Payroll', 2],
          ['MISC',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Work Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(zk.Widget.$("$piechart_3d").$n());
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script> 
    </div>

  </window>

</zk>
```

Now I need to get the json object and insert it into data (variable)

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Automation',     11],
      ['Manual',      2],
      ['Report',  2],
      ['Payroll', 2],
      ['MISC',    7]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank To Gusti Arya, I modified my zul like below:

```
 <zk>
 <window id="HomePage" apply = "com.dom.form.ChartForm" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:green">
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataJson;
        var data = [];

        function getData(jsonObj){
            dataJson = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

            var header = ['Task Name','Hours'];
            data.push(header);  

            for(var i = 0; i &lt; dataJson.length; i++){
                var temp = [];
                temp.push(dataJson[i].taskName);
                temp.push(dataJson[i].hours);

                data.push(temp);
            }

            return data;
        }

        google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart(){

            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Work Activities',
                is3D: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(zk.Widget.$("$piechart_3d").$n());
            chart.draw(chartdata, options);

        }    
    </script> 
    </div>
  </window>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Clients.evalJavaScript();` to pass Json from controller to view,
like this :

```
function drawChart(jsonObj){
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(zk.Widget.$("$piechart_3d").$n());
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

and in your controller :

```
TaskService ts = new TaskService();
listTask = ts.getTask(); 
json = new Gson().toJson(listTask);
Clients.evalJavaScript("drawChart('" + json + "')");
```